# Is every strong Banakh space isometric to the reals or at least a subset of the reals?

Tags: metric-spaces

This is a follow-up to my previous questions, here: [Is one condition of Banakh spaces redundant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754149/is-one-condition-of-banakh-spaces-redundant) and [A follow-up to a question on Banakh spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754649/a-follow-up-to-a-question-on-banakh-spaces). Refer to the first question for the definition of a Banakh space. I define a strong Banakh space to be a non-empty metric space $M$ such that for any point $x$ in $M$ and any positive real number $r$, the sphere $\{y:d(x,y)=r\}$ has cardinality $2$ and diameter $2r$. This is indeed a strengthening of the usual definition of Banakh space. My question is, is every Banakh space isometric to the real line, or at least a subset of the real line?

Comment: Worth noting that a proper subset of the real line will never satisfy your condition - pick any point in the subset, for all its spheres to have cardinality two it must be all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: [Stefan Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Banach) wasn't named Banakh

Comment: @Didier pretty sure Banakh spaces have nothing to do with Stefan Banach.

Comment: @MW You must be right. Sorry, never ever heard about Banakh spaces actually. What a coincidental name

Comment: Seems this mathoverflow discussion suggests answer is yes if you add completeness, no otherwise. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442772/a-metric-characterization-of-the-real-line/442872#442872. (I think this discussion was the origin of the concept of a Banakh space in the first place)